# JAX-WS Response String returns &lt; instead < and &gt; instead >

Tags: java, jax-ws

I am experiencing a problem in JAX-WS response.
 
That is my JAX-WS response returns a String Element with multiple Tags in it as per our client requirement. Where as all the Open and Close Angled Brackets are replaced with < = `&lt;` and > `&gt;`.

Eg :   `<return>&lt;Envelope&gt;</return>`

Can anyone help me out in this regard. In a way simple method. 
I have searched enough and got no clear answer for it. 
If I can get any code sample would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Seeing that `<return>` tags show correctly, then I suppose `&lt;Envelope&gt;` is just correctly escaped data. Angle brackets being part of the data should be escaped in an xml document, shouldn't they?

Comment: My client is not accepting it. Is there a way not to escape the tags

Answer (score -1):

You can try any of html sanitizer library to deal with these and other html tags auto conversion.